# How to load a file through Flume to Kafka Producer?

Tags: file, upload, apache-kafka, flume

I have a log file that I am trying to push to Kafka Producer through Flume agent. I am able to load the file to Kafka producer directly from my local machine. But my usecase is to use Flume agent to push to Kafka.

I have installed Flume and is up and running in my localhost @ http://localhost:35871

But, how do I pass that data file through Flume to Kafka?

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your **FLUME SINK** to dump data into **KAFKA BROKER**. 
To do this job, you have to include **KAFKA PRODUCER** in **FLUME SINK** that will become your **KAFKA SINK**.

**FLUME** also provides in-build [KAFKA-SINK](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/release-1.6.0/flume-ng-sinks/flume-ng-kafka-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/kafka/KafkaSink.java) from version 1.6.

Comment: Can you please explain how to put Kafka Producer in FLume sink?

Comment: @Sweet, please follow link :https://github.com/thilinamb/flume-ng-kafka-sink to read more about it.